# How to make the datetime column shown correctly on the ms excel?

Tags: javascript, xlsx, js-xlsx

I was using below api to generate the excel file.

```
var ws2 = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataForSheet, {skipHeader: true});
```

In the createtime column, only the date was displayed by default. Only when I click the cell, the datetime will be displayed. How can I resolve this issue? I hope the time displayed as well.
I just tried dateNF property like below.

```
  var ws2 = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(dataForSheet, {skipHeader: true,dateNF: 'YYYYMMDD HH:mm:ss'});
```

I will make my date type column incorrectly like below. The date column should not include the 00:00:00.
[image]

[image]

Comment: What were you expecting? Are you expecting the time to be shown as well? It looks like `json_to_sheet` has an option for that: `dateNF FMT 14 Use specified date format in string output`, according to the documentation.

Comment: Where a cell is specified as a date, Excel changes the value to it's own serial value that is decimal days since 1 Jan 1990, the original value is replaced (i.e. it doesn't store the original value if it was something other than an Excel date number). Everything else you see is a reformatting of that value. Note that for negative serial values, the integer part goes backwards from 1900-01-01 but the decimal part goes forward, so 1899-12-31 0600 is -1.25, not -0.75 as simple logic might indicate.

Comment: @Jorg, I have tried, but this dateNF property will affect the date type, it will make the date type column appended by useless 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

All i did was looping through my DATA, and cast my date variable using the popular library Moment.js.

```
    const fileName = 'MyFile_' + moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD")+ '.xlsx';

    // FORMATING DATES
    for( var k of this.myJsonArray)
    {
        k.myDateVariable= moment(k.myDateVariable).lang('fr').format("YYYY-MM-DD")
    }
    const ws: XLSX.WorkSheet = XLSX.utils.json_to_sheet(this.myJsonArray);
    const wb: XLSX.WorkBook = XLSX.utils.book_new();
    XLSX.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, 'test');
    XLSX.writeFile(wb, fileName);
```